# Redux cant access state after added

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have a parent component and one child component (custom function component). in my child component i have event handler that will change the state (redux) from the parent. everything work fine when i call the addProduct function the state is added i can see in my redux tools product state is changed. But Why after i added i cant access that state (console.log (product._id)) i get a error message a product is null and one thing make me confused is i can access that state in my JSX from parent Component ({JSON.stringify(product)}) but not after i added.

here is my code

```
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import {addProduct} from '../action/product';

    const ChildComponent = ({onClick}) => {
         return (
           <button onClick={onClick}>Add</button>
         )
    }          

    const ParentComponent = ({product}) => {
        const onNotFoundThenAddNew = () => {
            addProduct ({name : 'new product'});
            console.log(product._id);
        }
                 return (
                      <Fragment>
                          {JSON.stringify(product)}
                         <ChildComponent onClick={onNotFoundThenAddNew}/>
                      </Fragment>
                 )

    }

    ParentComponent.propTypes = {
        addProduct : PropTypes.func,
        product : PropTypes.object
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        product : state.product.product
    })

    export default connect (mapStateToProps, {addProduct}) (ParentComponent)
```

Comment: what does your product reducer look like?

Comment: @WebbH i think there is no problem from my reducer because i can see state added from my redux tool

Comment: `product : state.product.product` in your `mapStateToProps` seemed like a place the error could occur. i.e. the new product does not have a product property

Comment: if i have a problem from reducer or in mapStateToProps but why i can access the state using   {JSON.stringify(product)}

Comment: If `state.product.product` does not exist, then `product` in your component is null